# How to check if the actual time is between a time-range in string format

Tags: c, time, struct, compare

I'm using C on a raspberry pi and trying to do the following:
In a .txt file there are 2 times and 2 dates (in 4 different lines).
I was to check if the actual time is between these date-times.
So in  C I have:

1. Data.time1 (Char) containing: 00:00:00
2. Data.time2 (Char) containing: 23:59:59
3. Data.date1 (Char) containing: 1970-01-01
4. Data.date2 (Char) containing: 1970-01-01
5. Timenow (int) containing Unix value of the current time

I've tried a lot of options, but i guess i get stuck with having to use `struct tm`, which i don't understand fully.

Can anyone help me please with something functional?

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck? What format are you able to provide the actual time you want to compare? Are you able to convert it to same format as date<x> and time<x>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
void example(char *t1, char *d1, char *t2, char *d2)
{
    // t= "23:59:59"
    // d= "1970-01-01"
    struct tm from, to;
    time_t t_from, t_to, t_now;

    from.tm_year= atoi(d1)-1900;    // Year (current year minus 1900)
    from.tm_mon=  atoi(d1+5)-1;     // Month (0–11; January = 0)
    from.tm_mday= atoi(d1+8);       // Day of month (1–31)
    from.tm_hour= atoi(t1);         // Hours since midnight (0–23)
    from.tm_min=  atoi(t1+3);       // Minutes after hour (0–59)
    from.tm_sec=  atoi(t1+6);       // Seconds after minute (0–59)
    t_from= mktime(&from);          // now it is a numeric value

    to.tm_year= atoi(d2)-1900;      // Year (current year minus 1900)
    to.tm_mon=  atoi(d2+5)-1;       // Month (0–11; January = 0)
    to.tm_mday= atoi(d2+8);         // Day of month (1–31)
    to.tm_hour= atoi(t2);           // Hours since midnight (0–23)
    to.tm_min=  atoi(t2+3);         // Minutes after hour (0–59)
    to.tm_sec=  atoi(t2+6);         // Seconds after minute (0–59)
    t_to= mktime(&to);

    t_now= time(0);

    printf("%s\n",asctime(&from));
    printf("%s\n",asctime(&to));
    printf("%s\n",ctime(&t_now));

    if (t_from <= t_now && t_now <= t_to)
        printf("yes\n");
    else
        printf("no\n");
}
```